# IOS: Does constraint error or warning influence publish app to app store?

Tags: ios, constraints, appstore-approval

Does Constraint error or warning influence publish app to app store? Since it sometimes does not matter for running in simulator or device. Thanks!!

Comment: it means your code have bug. even it appear to be working, you still have to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about pure layout exception in the debugger, the answer is NO if the app is still usable and doesn't crash. 
Saying that if your layout exceptions break something in the UI that makes difficult the use of it, you have a chance of rejection.
I do agree with Bryan comment, if you know  you have a bug fix it as soon as possible.