# Can Apple reject an app which constraints after set, show this error?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard

i am using autolayout first time so  i am littile bit confuse about constraints. at the storyboard app constraints set success but at console show error -

[image: Error Description]

so my question is that can apple approve this app?

Comment: Apple will not reject your app based on layout warnings. It's always a good practice to get rid of the warnings though as they are there for a reason.

Comment: You are adding more constraints then required. This kind of message appears when you add certain constraints to already added constraints. Yes apple wont reject your app on this. May be due to the warning the UI might not be appearing well in some devices

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Auto-layout and deploy app to app store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340080/how-to-auto-layout-and-deploy-app-to-app-store)

Comment: thanks every buddy to response.

Answer (score 4):

Apple will not reject your app based on compiler/code or layout warnings. It's always a good practice to get rid of the warnings though as they are there for a reason. The rules and guidelines to follow are listed in the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

---

From: [IOS: Does constraint error or warning influence publish app to app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25279294/4078527)

> If you are talking about pure layout exception in the debugger, the
>   answer is NO if the app is still usable and doesn't crash.  Saying
>   that if your layout exceptions break something in the UI that makes
>   difficult the use of it, you have a chance of rejection.

Answer (score 2):

No, absolutely not. But these are very common errors , when constraints missed. You should fix error before submit app on `App Store`. You may be fix issue by changing the `priority`

Answer (score 1):

No Apple didn't refuse your app, you can sleep well. But in my opinion you should avoid that situations where you have warnings in autolayout.

usefull link: [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksandTips.html)

Answer (score 0):

Apple may overlook your error and may not reject your app due to constraint issue. However, it's good to resolve the issue first and then upload the app. So that, in future you will not face any design related problem in different screen-size(s). 
Before you upload your app, test it on different simulators (different sizes) and if possible on devices.